# React-Redux vs ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactcsstransitiongroup

I've encountered an issue connecting redux and ReactCssTransitionGroup. I'm wanting to transition old elements out and new ones in. The movement is fine but because redux is breaking the Parent/Child prop relationship, the old elements are being rendered with the new data before exiting.

There's a fiddle below that shows the relationship with a single child and only one level deep.

```
<Parent>
  <Child/>
</Parent>
```

For this case it would be easy enough to pass the props directly, but I was hoping for a solution that would play nicer with a more complex structure:

```
<GreatGrandParent>
  <GrandParent>
    <Parent>
      <Child/>
      <Child/>
      ...
```

How might one prevent the children from updating when the transition is triggered?

https://jsfiddle.net/haygoodjon/wx0L0bx7/2/

^
The fiddle is updating the old time before removing it from the dom. The expected behavior can be achieved by removing the connect on Child and passing the time prop directly from App